# Php clean filename multilanguage

Tags: php, security, upload, multilingual

I have hit a bit of a issue i need to clean a filename on upload but i need it to work multi language and not be a security risk.

So currently i am using the following.

```
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);
```

This is find for any english characters. But with any other languages Arabic Norwegian etc etc the characters gets stripped out.

So this filename would be

Kan få dette arbeids.mp3

output

Kan_f_dette_arbeids.mp3

Would this be enough to prevent hackers?

```
function preventCode($str){
        $special_chars = array("?", "[", "]", "/", "\\", "=", "<", ">", ":", ";", ",", "'", "\"", "&", "$", "#", "*", "(", ")", "|", "~", "`", "!", "{", "}");
        return str_replace($special_chars, '', $str);
    }

$string = 'สวัสดีชาวโลก ให้ได้ บุคคลนี้เริ่มต้น <?php echo \'hello\'; ?>';

echo preventCode($string);
```

What is the best way to deal with this if i removed the preg_replace could this cause a security risk with hackers trying to inject code via the filename?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question , but i run into same situation today and want to share what i ended to use :

```
 function preventCode($str){
    return preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/u", '', $str);
    }
```

> u : for unicode .

Testing your provided string example :

```
$string = 'สวัสดีชาวโลก ให้ได้ บุคคลนี้เริ่มต้น <?php echo \'hello\'; ?>';
echo preventCode($string);
```

**Result :**

> สวสดชาวโลก ใหได บคคลนเรมตน php echo hello